# Kubernetes GKE Ingress : 502 Server Error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm currently setting up a web app using google cloud platform but I ran into an issue while deploying with the GKE ingress controller.

I'm unable to access the app using my sub domain name. The page is showing this message:

```
502 Server Error
Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Despite having configured an health check the ingress seems to still not respond properly.
In the meantime my SSL certificate is working properly for my subdomain name.

This is my ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "myapp-static-addr"
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "frontend-ingress-config"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-service
          servicePort: 3333
  tls:
  - secretName: stage-ssl"
```

and this is my service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "frontend-config"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: frontend-server
  ports:
    - port: 3333
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000
```

and finally my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  labels:
    app: frontend-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: client-ssr
        image: eu.gcr.io/myapp-test/client-ssr
        ports:
        - name: client-port
          containerPort: 3000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "0.35"
          limits:
            cpu: "0.55"
        env:
          - name: CONFIG_ENV
            value: "STAGE"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: certificate
          mountPath: "/etc/certificate"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: certificate
          secret:
            secretName: stage-ssl
```

And this in the ingress describe:

```
Name:             frontend-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          34.106.6.15
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.26.31.88:8080)
TLS:
  stage-ssl terminates 
Rules:
  Host                  Path  Backends
  ----                  ----  --------
  test.myapp.com  
                        /   frontend-service:3333 (10.22.46.111:3000)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:       myapp-static-addr
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:                    {"k8s-be-32171--41df3ab30d90ff92":"HEALTHY","k8s1-41df3ab3-default-frontend-service-3333-5186e808":"HEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule:             k8s2-fr-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule:       k8s2-fs-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p
  ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-url-map:            k8s2-rm-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p
  ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert:                    k8s2-cr-opm63ww1-f42czv69pq6f2emd-5bd4c7395be5bd4e
  ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy:          k8s2-ts-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p
  ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy:                k8s2-tp-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s2-um-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name":"myapp-static-addr","networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig":"frontend-ingress-config"},"name":"frontend-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"test.myapp.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"frontend-service","servicePort":3333},"path":"/"}]}}],"tls":[{"secretName":"stage-ssl"}]}}

  networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig:  frontend-ingress-config
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                  From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync       18m                  loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p" created
  Normal  Sync       18m                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p" created
  Normal  Sync       18m                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p" created
  Normal  Sync       18m                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-ts-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p" created
  Normal  IPChanged  18m                  loadbalancer-controller  IP is now 34.106.6.15
  Normal  Sync       18m                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fs-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p" created
  Normal  Sync       16m                  loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p" updated
  Normal  Sync       16m                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-opm63ww1-default-frontend-ingress-8gn6ll7p" updated
  Normal  Sync       2m18s (x8 over 19m)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

How can I make my web app working ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: did you saw any error in cloud logging related to ' failed_to_pick_backend'?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found any entry like this in my logs.

Comment: Are there any guide you used when setting this up or did you use this [official GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)? Also, Can you share the logs that you see on the same timestamp when you encounter the 502 error?

Comment: Yes I used the officiel GCP documentation. After checking the request logs a warning is displayed with this error: `"statusDetails": "backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client"`

Comment: As per the documentation, manually setting the TCP timeout (keepalive) on the target service to greater than 600 seconds might resolve the issue. Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe GCE Ingress must have `defaultBackend` apparently, see my question [Is defaultBackend mandatory for Ingress (gce)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69018450)