# Is defaultBackend mandatory for Ingress (gce)?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

It seems that Ingress on GKE returns 503, if `defaultBackend` section is omitted, but I cannot find any documentation supporting that. But as soon as I remove it, all services on that Ingress return `503 Server Error`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  #defaultBackend:
  #  service:
  #    name: test-nginx
  #    port:
  #      number: 80
  rules:
    - host: test.example.com
      http:
        paths:
            - path: /*
              pathType: ImplementationSpecific
              backend:
                service:
                  name: test-nginx
                  port:
                    number: 80
    - host: test2.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: test2
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: I assume you are trying to access both `http://test.example.com` and `http://test2.example.com`?  And both work if you have the `defaultBackend` and both fail when you omit it?

Comment: And no, it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to help you to resolve your concerns about `defaultBackend` and the behavior mentioned in your description.

By [definition](http://A%20defaultBackend%20is%20often%20configured%20in%20an%20Ingress%20controller%20to%20service%20any%20requests%20that%20do%20not%20match%20a%20path%20in%20the%20spec.) a `defaultBackend` is often configured in an Ingress controller to service any requests that do not match a `path` in the `spec`.

An Ingress with no rules sends all traffic to a single default backend. The `defaultBackend` is conventionally a configuration option of the Ingress controller and is not specified in your Ingress resources.

**If none of the hosts or paths match the HTTP request in the Ingress objects, the traffic is routed to your default backend.**

Due to none of the hosts or paths match with the HTTP request it tries to reach the `defaultBackend` as you delete the `defaultBackend` the request send you the error 503.

If you want to avoid the use of the `defaultBackend` be sure the HTTP request match with the hosts or paths

if you want to learn more about this topic I would like to share with you the reference [Kubernetes Documentation > Concepts > Services, Load Balancing, and Networking > Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

In this reference there are some example about how to configure an ingress without `defaultBackend`

Have a great journey.